# Automatically create virtualenvs for new user accounts

Tags: linux, python, user-accounts, virtualenv

In Linux, how can I go about automatically creating virtualenvs for each newly created user account? Can it easily be done?

Comment: did you try installing it into `/etc/skel` (on a test box ;) ) and then creating a new user and see if it works for that user?

Comment: I'm not a *nix guru so i had no idea about `/etc/skel`. Thanks for mentioning it; I'll try it out and see. For anyone who does not know about `/etc/skel`, [here's some info](http://www.giglig.com/technology/what-is-etcskel-used-for) and [here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/using_skel.htm)